# Как настроить maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, tomcat

Пишу web приложение и деплою его на локальный сервер(Tomcat 9). Дело в том, что при любом малейшем изменении кода, даже на jsp странице мне приходится заново пересоберать проект (-clean, -instal). На старой машине такого не было, все мелкие изменения деплоились на сервер сами, будто то это имзменение в коде или на jsp. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно на старой машине стоял maven tomcat plugin, который занимался деплоем.  Правда есть ли плагин по tomcat9 не знаю.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/Andrey</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/